# Proper usage of user_likes permission of Facebook App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here I have an app, with logic as follow:

1. Check user whether he liked the page or not (login via `user_likes` permission and with Graph API call `/me/likes/{facebook_page_id}/`
2. If yes, proceed to obtain a coupon
3. If no, ask the user to like the page

Facebook App Review team said the 1st step violates Facebook App's rules:

> Gate access to your app, or some content within your app based on whether or not someone has liked a page.

But with `FBSDKLikeButton` or `FBSDKLikeControl`, there is no callback / delegate to know whether I can proceed to Step 2.

**My question is:** Is there any workarounds?

---

I'm working on iOS and Android App. Here are the codes of iOS related part:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                            initWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes/19292868552/"
                            parameters:@{@"fields": @"id"}
                            HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                    id result,
                                    NSError *error) {
  if(error) {
    // notify there is error
  } else {
    NSArray *likedID = [[result valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"];
    if(likedID != nil && likedID.count > 0) {
      // Liked, get coupon
    } else {
      // Not liked yet, show like button
      likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeButton alloc] init];
      likeButton.objectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers?rand=%d", rand()];
      likeButton.objectType = FBSDKLikeObjectTypePage;
      [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeFBclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [self.view addSubview:likeButton];
    }
  }
}];
```

where `likeFBclick:` is just forwarding users to obtain coupon.

Comment: The Facebook Platform Policy doesn't allow you to give someone something for liking your page. Doesn't matter if it is possible. It is not allowed

Comment: Without checking the user liked or not, It's quite meaningless to show a liked button and ask user to click it again. It's not user friendly at all. Why does FB forbid from doing so?

Comment: It is really useful for the user to be able to unlike the page if they don't want to like it anymore

Comment: Agree, but the logic requires users to like the Page in order to obtain coupon... still I have to detect whether user has unliked the page, and tell him that he has to like the page in order to send him away...

Comment: I told you in my first post that you are not allowed to give the user anything for liking your page. Giving them a coupon is something

Comment: @WizKid, I am also requiring the same logic to detect whether the user has liked a particular page in facebook. I am using "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/" to detect the page like. Is this feature feasible now in 2017? Or any restrictions from Facebook to approve user_likes?

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user liked the page? Like gating is not allowed

Comment: Hi @WizKid , 2 years ago, I would like to have a script to check whether he likes the page or not. If he hasn't liked the page, invite him to like the page. But anyways, the project changed, and such flow doesn't need anymore.

Comment: My comment was for @KarthikKPN who commented 20 hours ago